# How to convert old list of string into new list of int

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, integer

I want the strings converted into integer.
tried doing it this way but for some reason it doesn't work

```
newList = []
myList = [['1', '2'], ['3', '4'], ['5', '6']]

for i in range (len(myList)):
    for j in i:
        
        b = int(myList[i][j])
        newList.append(b)
    
   
   
print(newList)
```

I want the outcome to look like this:

[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]

Comment: You are using range, so `i` is an int, iterate directly over the list

Answer (score 2):

thats the way:

```
myList = [['1', '2'], ['3', '4'], ['5', '6']]
new_list = [[int(i) for i in e] for e in myList]
```

with `for i in range(len(myList)):` you iterate through the index of the list, and not the elements itself. What you wanted to do:

```
newList = []
myList = [['1', '2'], ['3', '4'], ['5', '6']]

for i in myList:
    stack = []
    for j in i:
        stack.append(int(j))
    newList.append(stack)

print(newList)
```

Answer (score 2):

Answer above is very good, but I'd like to make code with your intention

```
newList = []
myList = [['1', '2'], ['3', '4'], ['5', '6']]

for i in range(len(myList)):
    tempList=[]#we need tempList to make element list
    #for j in i -> this makes error because for loop cant use in integer without range()
    for j in range(len(myList[i])):
        b = int(myList[i][j])
        tempList.append(b)#make element list
    newList.append(tempList)#append element list to newlist

print(newList)
```

I wish this can help you. Thanks :)

Comment: okeyish, but I'd say, it would be better to iterate over the list itself rather than creating a list of indices and iterate over those....from a pythonic point of view

Answer (score 1):

you can also use map:

```py
newList = [list(map(int, i)) for i in myList]
```

Actually, for this type of problem list comprehension and `map` are somewhat interchangeable and the answer uses both.

Comment: hmm, if you wish to use map why not `map( lambda i: map( int, i), a)`?

Comment: yes i also thought about it but forgot to edit my answer xD

Answer (score 0):

While i would use one of the solutions given by other members, here one simple  one using `numpy`:

```py
import numpy
myList = [['1', '2'], ['3', '4'], ['5', '6']]
newlist = numpy.array( myList, dtype=int )
```

Memory wise probably not the best, but quite good readability. Though, at the end it is not a list, but a numpy array.